# Azure API management - how to access product information

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In APIM, I am trying to access the Product information at API level policy, as i have to execute some logic based on product name. I am using the below code

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="ProductName" value="@{
            return  context.Product.Name;
        }" />
```

But, when trying to post request from postman, i can see the below exception in trace.

```
{
source: "set-variable",
timestamp: "2020-08-19T14:42:24.4936554Z",
elapsed: "00:00:00.0358409",
data:- {
messages:- [
-{
message: "Expression evaluation failed.",
expression: " return context.Product.Name; ",
details: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
},
"Expression evaluation failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
]
}
}
```

Why it is null ? is this the case, that i can't access the property in inbound scope. Need guidance. Or, is there any other way i can access the Product.Name property.
Thank you.

Comment: If it helps you, please accept it as answer. Click the checkbox to turn to green.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Product Name with `@(context.Product.Name)`.

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="aaa" value="@(context.Product.Name)" />
    <set-body template="liquid">
    {
        "success": true,
        "var1": {{context.Variables["aaa"]}}
    }
    </set-body>
</inbound>
```

In test, set the product name as `Starter` and you will get the snapshot as below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joey Cai, Thank you for response. For me, Object reference exception is coming in the first assignment only . i.e.   <set-variable name="aaa" value="@(context.Product.Name)" /> , as exception is shared in question, or, did i missed something here ?

Comment: Just use `@(context.Product.Name)` instead of `@{  return  context.Product.Name;  }`.

Comment: See what call you're making exactly. context.Product will be null if API/service subscription is used. You can check subscription scope in Azure portal in subscription list